# Is there anyway to use cmake with mqueue.h on ubuntu

Tags: cmake, ipc

CMakeFiles/mqcreate.dir/mqcreate1.cc.o: In function `main':
mqcreate1.cc:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to`mq_open'
mqcreate1.cc:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to `mq_close'

Comment: You need to link against the correct libraries to use these functions.  Refer to `man mq_open` on Ubuntu.  It should tell you which one to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   find_library(LIBRT rt) 
   if(LIBRT)
      target_link_libraries(target_name ${LIBRT})
   endif()
```

[link to the source](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000477460-Clion-adding-lrt-in-cmake)

Comment: but I still confused that "add_compile_options(-lrt) " not work

Comment: @Ericlee Because it's not a compile option but a library used during linking.  `find_library` is probably overkill and `target_link_libraries(target_name rt)` should suffice because it's a standard OS library that the linker can find on it's own.